# Can we embed MongoDB to a standalone App?

Tags: mongodb

I have a hosted web application that has MongoDB as its DB. Now, I have a requirement to develop app that runs locally on user machine even if there is no network connection. That's why I need to embed MongoDB server to my local app. How can I embed MongoDB with my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but it isn't pretty and will force your app to be AGPL licensed. If you are interested take a look at how the tools handle the --dbpath option.

Source: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/RjlWqT0_tzQ

Comment: The answer does not satisfy the how in the question.